# Is there a way to generate an audio file from MusiXTeX?

Tags: musixtex

I need to type some sheet music and it would be nice if I'd be able to produce an audio file, e.g. `midi`. As far as I remember Lilypond is able to do it. Just because I'm more familiar with LaTeX, I'd like to learn rather MusiXTeX.

But would I be able to generate an audio file with MusiXTeX as well?

Comment: There's no mention of audio or midi in the documentation for MusiXTeX. But yes, you can do this with lilypond. For conventional music notation the basics aren't so hard to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official MusiXTeX documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf), which doesn't mention that possibility, it is inferred that it's impossible.